# How to echo selected radio value in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.6

I have user_type column in my users table. On my register blade view i would like to show form with different fields according to the user_type.

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline mr-4">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="user_type" id="exampleRadios1" value="0" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
    I'm a user
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline mr-4">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="user_type" id="exampleRadios2" value="1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
    I'm a professional
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline mr-4">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="user_type" id="exampleRadios3" value="2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
    I'm a facility/business
  </label>
</div>
```

I'm trying to do something like this

```
@if( Request::get('user_type') == 0 )
Show user registration form
@elseif( Request::get('user_type') == 1 )
    Show professional user registration form
@elseif( Request::get('user_type') == 2 )
    Show business registration form
@endif
```

But it doesnt work. It only shows show user registration form as output and does not change according to the selection

Comment: You can append your forms by JavaScript help, `if(user_type === 0){
.....}else if(user_type === 1){
.......}else{
.....}` using blade if won't work because it's not data that comes from database this is front-end design then do it by front end.

Comment: Is the `Request::get('user_type')` actually numeric? Maybe you should be testing for `Request::get('user_type') == "0" instead of ` == 0.`   Maybe `dd(Request::get('user_type)` and see what it says.

Comment: it is numerice but the problem is as im a user is checked by default it shows show user registration form, but when i change the option it does not change the form. Maybe javascript is need for this.. but i thought to check if there's any way to solve this

Comment: if i change to "0" nothing shows up

Comment: if you `dd(Request::get('user_type')` when you submit with the pro or business checked do you get 1 or 2 instead of 0?

Comment: Nope... it doesnt change